# How to pass value from flash to php

Tags: php, flash

Hello i am new to the flash . Just i want to how to pass values from Flash variable to php 
i am using this code

```
var myVars:LoadVars = new LoadVars(); 
myVars.playerName = "Some Body";
myVars.playerTime = Timer;

myVars.send("index.html", "_parent", "POST");`
```

it show error - >

> Warning: 1060: Migration issue: The method LoadVars is no longer supported.  For more information, see the URLVariables class, the URLRequest.urlVariables and URLRequest.postData properties, and the URLLoader.dataFormat property..

please guide me how do i resolve this error . i am using CS4 for flash  and AS3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadVars()` is AS2 only. You need to use `URLLoader`. Try this class:

```
package
{
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * @author Marty Wallace
     * @version 1.00
     */
    public class PHPData extends Object
    {
        /**
         * Sends data to a PHP script
         * @param script A URL to the PHP script
         */
        public function send(script:String, vars:URLVariables):void
        {
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(script);

            req.data = vars;
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.load(req);

            // listeners
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _complete);
        }

        /**
         * Called when a response has been received from a PHP script
         * @param e Event.COMPLETE
         */
        private function _complete(e:Event):void
        {
            var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);

            var i:String;
            for(i in vars)
            {
                trace(i + ": " + vars[i]);
            }

            e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _complete);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do what you're doing like so:

```
var php:PHPData = new PHPData();
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

vars.playerName = "Some Body";
vars.playerTime = Timer;

php.send("index.php", vars);
```

Another thing I noticed was you're using send to send data to a **.html** document rather than a **.php** document..

---

A small tutorial on creating this class to use (based on comments):

1. Click File -> New -> ActionScript file.
2. Paste the above package (first chunk of code) into the new file.
3. Save the file in the **same directory** as your .fla file.
4. Paste my second snippet of code into the **timeline** of your .fla file.

All should work from here.

---

Here is a .zip containing an example you can use.

http://junk.projectavian.com?f=phpdata.zip

Comment: Sorry i am new to this , where i paste this code , in actionscript itself or in php file please tell me

Comment: If i paste this code in action script then i got this error - >            1037: Packages cannot be nested.

Comment: Thank you for your valuble reply .  i did every thing what you r mentioned in your answer but still i get the same error "1037: Packages cannot be nested.".

Comment: Thank you so much for your zipped file thank you once again for your timely help. now i get clear

Comment: One more help if i use this class in another program i receive the following errors : could u please help me whats going wrong . i publish the fla through flash 8.
These errors are coming up when I test the movie:
• The class or interface 'URLVariables' could not be loaded.
• The class or interface 'flash.net.URLRequest' could not be loaded.
• The class or interface 'flash.net.URLLoader' could not be loaded.